# Very very persistent Invalid Entitlements error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, xcode4

I have done quite a bit of research on this issue and have been running up against a wall all day.  I know that there are many posts on this but so far none have been helpful.  I am running the latest XCode 4.2 on Lion.  I have tried deleting, cleaning and replacing the entitlements file.  I have reloaded all of my provisioning profiles and verified that the build settings in both the project and the target are correct.

I can run in debug mode on the device but if I archive it as an ad-hoc and try to install the .ipa on an iPad I get an error that says "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements".

In the latest xCode there is no "Get-task-allow" or "can be debugged" check box on the entitlements file that I can see.

In the past when I have encountered this problem it was a simple fix but now it seems like nothing is working.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On XCode 4 entitlements are no longer required for ad-hoc builds. Try deleting your entitlements file completely and seeing if that helps. [You can refer to this technical note for more information.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TROUBLESHOOTING_GUIDE-CODE_SIGNING_ENTITLEMENTS)